# How to use Jackson to deserialse an XML element with both value and attribute

Tags: java, xml, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have been struggling to find a way to use Jackson to de-serialise this XML into Java:

```
<bitstream encoding="base64Binary">ew0KIklucH...bkpBTVMgQUEiDQp9</bitstream>
```

I have searched for ages and I can't find a solution to what seems a common XML structure: an element with both a value and attribute.
Can anyone help me?

Here is my current code:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Bitstream {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String encoding;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "bitstream")
    private String bitstrm;

    public String getEncoding() {
        return encoding;
    }
    public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }
    public String getBitstream() {
        return bitstrm;
    }
    public void setData(String bitstrm) {
        this.bitstrm = bitstrm;
    }
```

This sets the *encoding* attribue, but *bitstrm* is null.
Do I need to create a custom de-serialiser... or just have a "Duh!" moment when I see the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `@JacksonXmlText` instead of `@JacksonXmlProperty` for the `bitstrm` field:

```
@JacksonXmlText
private String bitstrm;
```

Comment: Many thanks @atheistnapkin - that solved my problem. As I understand the explanation, 'bitstrm' has to be the only exposed property and it gets set because of that - i.e it doesn't matter than its name is diferent from that in the xml ('bitstream'). You are star!